# How do I get Array inside array in PHP using Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

How do I get `web_hi_res_512.png` value.

```
Array ( 
  [upload_data] => 
    Array ( [file_name] => web_hi_res_51216.png
            [file_type] => image/png 
            [file_path] => C:/xampp/htdocs/elearning/uploads/ 
            [full_path] => C:/xampp/htdocs/elearning/uploads/web_hi_res_51216.png 
            [raw_name]  => web_hi_res_51216 [orig_name] => web_hi_res_512.png 
            [client_name] => web_hi_res_512.png [file_ext] => .png [file_size] => 84.94 
            [is_image]  => 1 
            [image_width] => 512 
            [image_height] => 512 
            [image_type] => png 
            [image_size_str] => width="512" height="512"
    ) 
)
```

Comment: Which sub array is required, it is not clear from question.

Comment: `$aray['upload_data']['orig_name'];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you assign this array to a variable $array:

```
echo $array['upload_data']['file_name'];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?=$array['upload_data']['file_name'];?>
```

You can get like this

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $array['1st_array_key']['2nd_array_key'];
```

you can access it like below

```
echo $array['upload_data']['filename'];
```